# Exit maths mode quickly on TexStudio

Tags: math-mode, texstudio, keyboard

I recently created a macro on TexStudio to create a mathematical environment. Very simply, the script for this macro is  `$%|$` and this command is triggered when I write "mk".

The problem is that I have to press the right arrow or the $ symbol to exit the math mode, which wastes time. Is it possible to define a macro to exit math mode when I press a key (like Tab or a letter)?

Comment: The regular key combinations (that work in any program) might be sufficient here, such as `ctrl`+`right arrow` (skip a word) or the `End` key (go to the end of the line).

Comment: Currently, I have `ctrl` + `right arrow`, but it is annoying to hit the `right arrow` key.